# unity3d - Object keeps falling down

Tags: unity, physics, rigid-body-dynamics

I have an object that moves towards another object using this line :

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

this is it's attributes:

[image]

It doesn't use gravity, kinematic and it's Y position is frozen, but it keeps falling to the floor and colliding with it. How do prevent that and keep it floating ?

Comment: Doesn't make sense that it should fall given your configuration. Are you sure it's the correct object? Could it be that the object has a parent object that also has a rigidbody, and that one does use gravity? Also, where is the target's position? Do you actually see it moving towards the target at all, or just falling down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

You do know that if the target's position is on the ground, then your object's position will also try to match the objects's `Y` position. You can try to make an object and check all the constraints, and it will still work if you give it  a Translate script, because scripts tend to override constraints.

If you want to make your object go to the target, but still keep his `Y` position, you could just make a new target vector :

```
new Vector3(target.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y, target.transform.position.z);
```

and make this the target, so your objects keeps his `Y` position since he's already in it, and translates on the `XZ-plane` instead.